# SQL SVR 08 R2 Limit a field to specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

For example, say I have field 'Gender' and I want to allow only the values Male, Female or Unisex. Is this possible in the SQL server management studio?

Update: So far the solution is pointing towards the 'Check constraints' function which can be found by right-clicking on the desired column.

Still, I'm getting syntax errors. Any thoughts on how I should type up the constraint?

Answer: Turns out I just needed to type it likes this

```
Gender = 'Male' OR Gender = 'Female' OR Gender = 'Unisex'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike MySQL, MSSQL doesn't have `ENUM` data type. The only want you can do this is to trap the value in the application level. Or by using `CHECK` constraint

```
ColumnName varchar(10) 
CHECK(ColumnName IN ('Male', 'Female', 'Unisex')) 
DEFAULT 'Unisex'
```

Comment: Or save the enum as a tinyint and check for a numeric range.

Comment: I found the option that allows you to define check constraints but I keep getting a validation error.

Comment: @Zizo47, if you are getting an error, please edit your question and post the full text error. Don't try to put it in a comment, code and comments not get along very well

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:
 - Create another table and create a one to many relationship from the primary table to the Gender.
 - Create an constraint like the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
   Id int NOT NULL,
   Gender varchar(200)
   CONSTRAINT chk_Gender CHECK (Gender IN ('Male', 'Unisex', 'Female'))
)
```

Comment: This works, but I'm not a big fan of filling my DB with static tables like this.